# Conversion of Access backend to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2007, database-migration

I'm stuck and need your help.

I've been asked to migrate our MS Access 2007 application's backend to SQL Server 2005.
I'm using the upsizing wizard and creating an ADB for this task. I have upsized tables but many queries are showing error.

The fact that this queries get created as SQL functions or views is not well understood by me. How does this function get invoked from access app remains a question mark for me.

Whether this project will work if I create the functions/views with the same query name in access in SQL server manually.

How will the end output look like? I'm a newbie and want little explanation on the whole process of handling queries and migrating them.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: SQL Server **2005** is no longer supported by Microsoft - upgrading to a "dead-end" product seems like a waste. If you upgrade, you should upgrade to a more recent version - at least 2008 R2, better yet 2012 or 2014 ....

Comment: SQL Server does not have a 'built in' front end, so you need to migrate all your forms and reports to something else. Either ASP.Net (web) or a thick client in C# or something

Comment: Thank u Marc and NickMy front end wil remain as MS access itself , only the backend is moved to sql , can someone give me a more specific reply.